# Context bounds for generic polymorphic data in collection

Tags: scala, generics, polymorphism, implicit

I have the simplified situation:

```
abstract sealed trait Top
class A[T] extends Top
class B[T] extends Top

class Typeclass[T]
implicit def a[T] = new Typeclass[A[T]]
implicit def b[T] = new Typeclass[B[T]]
```

Now I have a `Map[String, Top]` and want to use an operation on all values in the map that require the presence of an instance of `Typeclass` to be available in the context. This will not compile as the concrete types of the values in the map are not visible from its type and I can therefore not set a context bound for them.

Is there a way to tell the compiler that in fact there will always be an instance available? In this example this is given as there are implicit functions to generate those instances for every concrete subtype of `Top`.

Or is the only solution to use a `HList` and recurse over its type requiring all the instances to be in context?

Comment: Is there a reason not to define the typeclass instance on Top instead (or in supplement?) Anyway, the compiler will not be satisfied by knowing that an instances will be available. It will want to know which instance, at compile time.

Comment: @DidierDupont The implementation of the `Typeclass` instance depends on the type `T` as well as members of `A` or `B` (in my real world use-case). I don't see how I would go about implementing that on `Top`.

Comment: @DidierDupont With pattern matching I can differentiate between `A` and `B` but as far as I know I can't get the type `T` from it (without matching for every possible type `T`).

Comment: Ok, going to an answer to get more room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using some variation on this adaptation of Oleg's [Existentials as universals](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Existentials.html) in this sort of situation ... pack the the type class instance along with the value it's the instance for,

```
abstract sealed trait Top
class A[T] extends Top
class B[T] extends Top

class Typeclass[T]
implicit def a[T] = new Typeclass[A[T]]
implicit def b[T] = new Typeclass[B[T]]

trait Pack {
  type T <: Top
  val top: T
  implicit val tc: Typeclass[T]
}

object Pack {
  def apply[T0 <: Top](t0: T0)(implicit tc0: Typeclass[T0]): Pack =
    new Pack { type T = T0 ; val top = t0 ; val tc = tc0 }
}

val m = Map("a" -> Pack(new A[Int]), "b" -> Pack(new B[Double]))

def foo[T: Typeclass](t: T): Unit = ()

def bar(m: Map[String, Pack], k: String): Unit =
  m.get(k).map { pack =>
    import pack._ // imports T, top and implicit tc
    foo(top)      // instance available for call of foo
  }

bar(m, "a")
```

Comment: Will it fare better than pattern matching when foo signature is less trivial? My gut feeling is that it might (certainly, it will not be worse), but I cannot pinpoint a case where it would.

Comment: Pattern matching is always vulnerable to erasure issues. This approach isn't because the instance is selected at a point where the static type of the value is known.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in comment it would be more convenient to have the typeclass defined on `Top`, and it might be done with pattern matching.

supposing part of the definition of the typeclass is

```
def f[T](t: T): FResult[T],
```

and you have the corresponding implentations

```
def fOnA[T](t: A[T]): FResult[A[T]] = ...
def fOnB[T](t: B[T]): FResult[B[T]] = ...
```

Then you can define

```
def fOnT(t: Top) : FResult[Top] = t match {
  case a: A[_] => fOnA(a) 
    // provided an FResult[A[T]] is an FResult[Top], 
    // or some conversion is possible
  case b: B[_] => fOnB(b)
}
```

If is both legal and safe to call a generic method, such as `fOnA[T]` with an existential (`a` matching `A[_]`)

However, it might be difficult to convince the compiler that the parameter you pass to `f` or the result you get are ok, given the reduced information of the existential. If so, please post the signatures you need.

Comment: What if `fOnA` and `fOnB` have (different) context bounds on their type `T`?

Comment: It's legal and safe to call the method at an existential, but it's neither legal nor safe to coerce the result back to the expected result type of `fOnT` ... you would need an unsafe cast in the body of the case clauses to get this to compile.

Comment: @MilesSabin : true in general, but it will work in many case, e.g it the return type is simply not parametric, or covariant. Parameters could be a problem too. Obviously, monoids on every A[T] and B[T] do not make it a monoid on Top, and casts will not make it so.